# Making printf to printf x[i] where is the actuall value of i and just not "x[i]"

Tags: c, string, printing

I learning C and trying and I have written a small program.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
int *x = malloc(sizeof(int)*3);
int i;
for(i=0;i<3; i++){
   x[i] = i*i;
   printf("x[i] = %d\n", x[i]);
   }
free(x);
}
```

Right now the output is (ofc it is)

> x[i] = 0
>   x[i] = 1
>   x[i] = 4

My question is, how would I change the code to get the output?

> x[0] = 0
>   x[1] = 1
>   x[2] = 4

Comment: I cannot suppress the suspicion that sometimes the solution would present itself if some effort were made to properly explain the problem in natural language (even for non-native speakers). It's likely that in such an explanation the term "how to print the index" would occur, which looks like a solvable problem.

Comment: Read the first chapter of your beginner-level C book. It will tell you how to print integers. Since you already managed to print `x[i]`, printing `i` shouldn't even be a problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
printf("x[%d] = %d\n",i, x[i]);
```